# Generic function json to POJO?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

I am converting my json string to POJO using jackson `ObjectMapper`

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, ResourceTypes.getClassName(resourceType))
```

`ResourceTypes.getClassName(resourceType)` returns different class names.

Ex: Student.class, Hotel.class, etc

Now I wanted to write a generic function for this like:

```
public static T toPOJO(String json, Class<T> type){


        try {

            return JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, type);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However this gives error unknown type `T`. How to write this function to return any POJO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, may be this will work

```
public static <T> T toPOJO(String json, Class<T> type) {

    try {

        return JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, type);

    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

For any issues please let me know.

Comment: Yes this removes the compilation error, but somehow thw function does not work properly. Other exception occurs in `JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, type)`